# Why does .next() returns event's object itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working on the select's onchagne event handler which checks if there is another select in a block next to it and accordingly inserts a new select element or updates existing one. I've found out how to check if other select exists, that is using `next.().is('slecect')`, however I'm wondering why the `.next()` function when used on its own returns the event's object itself in the following code:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
    <select name="Category" title="Select Category">
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2">option 2</option>
    </select>
</form>


$('select').change(function(e){
    var $target = $(e.target);
    console.log($target.next('select'));        
});
```

Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yEx2p/1/)

Comment: It returns empty jQuery object because no element match it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering why the `.next()` function when used on its own returns the event's object itself in the following code

It doesn't return an event object, it returns a jQuery object. That jQuery object will either have a single `select` element in it, or be empty, depending on whether the following sibling is a `select` element. You can tell by looking at the `length`:

```
console.log($target.next('select').length);
```

...which will be `0` (there is no "next" [immediately following sibling] element, or it's not a `select`) or `1` (there is and it is).

Comment: I've self suggested because if I expand the object tree in the console it shows in context node all properties of the event's object.

Comment: @Dimt: Yeah, jQuery objects are fairly complex. When you do something like `$target.next(...)`, the jQuery object it creates and returns will have a reference to the `$target` jQuery object, so you can use features like the [`end()` function](http://api.jquery.com/end/). For instance, if you do `var $next = $target.next('select');` then `var $end = $next.end();`, `$end === $target` is `true`: http://jsbin.com/xusobofa/1

Comment: Thanks alot for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Check it properly with:

```
$target.next().is("select");
```